# How to ask user for matrix and find zeros?

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and trying to figure this out the simplest way. I have to ask the user to input a matrix (all the numbers inside one matrix), and determine if the matrix has any zeros or not. If it does, how do I determine the place of the zeros?

Comment: Have a look at the `input` and `find` functions. In Matlab, type `doc find` for example

Comment: I tried many ways, but it is not working

Comment: Please add the code (by *editing* your question) for one of the ways you have tried so we can see what you have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started, it uses `input` to ask the user for a number of rows and columns and then prompts for a each entry seperately (no checks are made to ensure data is a number).
The code then uses `find` to locate any entries equal to zero.

```
c = input('How many columns: ');
r = input('How many rows: ');

% Ask user to enter each number individually (no checks made)
for i=1:r
    for j=1:c
        matrix(i,j) = input(sprintf('Enter element R%dC%d: ',i,j));
    end
end
fprintf('Here is your matrix:\n');
disp(matrix);
fprintf('\n');

% If any entries are == 0
if any(find(matrix==0))
    [zeros_r,zeros_c]=find(matrix==0); %Find zero positions
    %Loop through zero entries and print
    for i=1:length(zeros_r)
        fprintf('Zero at Row%d Column%d\n', zeros_r(i),zeros_c(i));
    end
else
    fprintf('No zeros found\n');
end
```

Comment: In this context it seems a bit counter intuitive to first store the input as string and then use str2num. I would recommend leaving the `'s'` part out of the input command.

Comment: You are correct, I started my answer entering as a list and did not fix this. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to code this is if you let the user input the matrix in valid matlab syntax.

The program would then be:

```
M=input('input your matrix:')
[r c]=find(~M)
```

A sample input would be:

```
[1 1 1;1 0 0]
```

Comment: I agree but this assumes some knowledge on the user's part, although not necessarily difficult to do. My answer sacrifices simplicity for user-friendliness but of course this totally depends on the target user of the code!